# SAS CATX 50+variables

Tags: sas, concatenation

Looking for a shortcut here...

I am using CATX to concatenate a series of variables that have gone through a cleansing process (T1 through T50)...but it seems I am stuck with referencing all variables that I wish to concatenate. I was hoping the trusty old ':' would come to the rescue (attempt referenced below)...

No success -

```
OPERATE = CATX('',T:);
```

No success -

```
OPERATE = CATX('',T1-T50);
```

No success -

```
OPERATE = CATX('',T1--T50);
```

Am I stuck typing out 'x' amount of variables...or can I some how imply all T# variables with one short snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need OF when you are using space separated lists (which the default lists are).

```
OPERATE = CATX(' ',of T1--T50);
```

Or `of t1-t50` or `of t:` or any other variable list.

Comment: Note my trivial change to the first argument - `''` is incorrect, though irrelevantly so.  Only in a very few places in SAS can you have a null string, almost all strings like that are converted to one length spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the note - Going to roll with "T:" as this list of T variables will always grow...but I must be sure that no other variables get created with the T prefix...maybe I will recreate the variables to something more explicit (T_#)....regardless, check and +1 (again)...

Comment: @SMW I would recommend even better - like `TIMEVAR_#` (for example).  If you make it more descriptive it's better for readability _and_ uniqueness.